# How to prove the property of a full row rank matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Consider a $(n-d) \times n$ matrix A, $(0<d<n)$, and A is full row rank. How to prove that there is a unique $n \times n$ invertible matrix $P$, such that $AP=(0, I_{n-d})$?

My idea is to use the kernel space of A is d-dimensional space. But how can I find the rest $n-d$ vectors for $P$? And how to prove the uniqueness of P?

Comment: you should have been able to figure out that if $AP = (0, I_{n-d})$ then you can re-scale the first column of $P$ and get the same result so $P$ can't possibly be unique. More broadly:  $AP=(0, I_{n-d}) =AP'\implies A(P-P')=\mathbf 0$ then your claim of uniqueness implies $\dim \ker A = 0$ which is impossible since $A$ has more columns than rows.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is wrong. You can easily find counterexamples. Let
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then some of the possible choices for $P$ are the following:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 &  1 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 &  0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \;\;\;,\;\;\;
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 &  1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 &  0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 &  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \\
\phantom{xx}
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 &  1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 &  0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \;\;\;,\;\;\;
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 &  1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 &  0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 &  0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$